# How to add the same number for the same item?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

I want to know how I can add the same number for each text values in a column.

For instance:

```
| Text | Number |
| AAA  |      1 |
| AAA  |      1 |
| BBB  |      2 |
| CCC  |      3 |
| AAA  |      1 |
| DDD  |      4 |
| BBB  |      2 |
```

Whatever if someone knows the solution in DAX, or the query to populate a column in SQL Server, then I will be glad to have the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select col1, dense_rank() over(order by col1) as val
from tablename
```

Comment: I think you should remove `partition by col1` clause.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use DAX, create a calculated column:

```
Number = RANKX(TableName,TableName[Text],,ASC,Dense)
```

RANKX function iterates over your table, and assigns a rank based on Ascending sorted [Text].